# Cococs2d-x keyboard implementation

Tags: windows, macos, cocos2d-x, keyboard-events, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm using cocos2d-x to make a game for windows, mac, and linux
I want to use keyboard in my game but there is no official keyboard implementation in 
cocos2d-x3.0alpha. I read a lot of forum posts about keyboard implementation and I've seen some customized cocos2d-x braches but I already modified my cocos2d-x so I need the code to place in CCDirector or other classes. Can someone give me the code on how to get this working? (not a project I would like code that will work on all of the above platforms) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I got it working I also made a tutorial which you can check here:
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/39145

We will start by making two functions in the scene we want keyboard on.
They will be:

OurScene.h:

```
void keyPressed(cocos2d::EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, cocos2d::Event *event);
void keyReleased(cocos2d::EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, cocos2d::Event *event);
```

OurScene.cpp:

```
void OurScene::keyPressed(cocos2d::EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, cocos2d::Event *event)
{

}
void OurScene::keyReleased(cocos2d::EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, cocos2d::Event *event)
{

}
```

These functions will be called when we press/release a key on the keyboard.
Next we need a listener to look for the keyboard we will create it like so (I did it in the init function)

```
auto keyboardListener = EventListenerKeyboard::create();
keyboardListener->onKeyPressed = CC_CALLBACK_2(OurScene::keyPressed, this);
keyboardListener->onKeyReleased = CC_CALLBACK_2(OurScene::keyReleased, this);
EventDispatcher::getInstance()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(keyboardListener, this); // use if your version is below cocos2d-x 3.0alpha.1
// use this: Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(keyboardListener, this); if you are using cocos2d-x 3.0alpha.1 and later!
```

This code creates a keyboard listener and then setting what functions will be called when the key is pressed or released.
Now Our program can detect keyboard!

Wait… How do I know what key is pressed? It is simple! Let me show you:

```
//put this inside keyPressed or keyReleased
if (keyCode == EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_W)
{
    CCLog("W key was pressed");
}
```

This piece of code will check what is the key-code of the key that was pressed. The list of key-codes is inside the EventKeyboard class. To use a keycode you just type:
`EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_**whatever key**` - you will usually get a list of available keys to chose from.

Comment: I added in the tutorial you linked, just in case your link dies.

Comment: There is a small mistake in the code here, where "listener" us used instead of "keyboardListener"